# ¿Como navegar al siguiente elemento visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Soy novato con jQuery.

Tengo una lista ordenada `<ol>` y al principio del código establezco que elementos `<li>` estarán visibles dependiendo de una opción elegida.

```
<li></li> 
<li style = "display: none"></li> 
<li style = "display: none"></li> 
<li></li>
```

Cree un button con la función .next() para navegar entre elementos `<li>` pero me lleva a una que esta oculto. ¿Como hago que el button me lleve al siguiente elemento visible?.

intente con:

```
$(this).nextAll('li:visible')
```

Pero no me funciono, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade una clase `visible` a los elementos visibles, y haces un `.find('.visible')`

```
<ol>
  <li class="visible">Item 1</li>
  <li style="display: none">Item 2</li>
  <li style="display: none">Item 3</li>
  <li class="visible">Item 4</li>
<ol>

$('ol').find('.visible')

// o tambien

$('ol>li.visible')
```

Otra alternativa, es añadirle una clase a los elementos invisibles que puede ser `hide` y con `.find(':not(.hide)')`, también te trae los elementos visibles.

```
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li class="hide" style="display: none">Item 2</li>
  <li class="hide" style="display: none">Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
<ol>

$('ol').find('li:not(.hide)')

// o tambien

$('ol>li:not(.hide)')
```

Otra alternativa es accediendo a la propiedad style del elemento, pero lleva mas de trabajo porque tienes que iterar cada li.

Puedes hacer una funcion donde le pasas el li y que retorne true o false si es visible

```
function isVisible(liElement){
  return liElement.style.display === 'block';
}

// si quieres buscar el oculto usas el operador !
!isVisible( li )
```

Comment: Seria mejor agregar un ejemplo ya que el OP quiere "navegar entre elementos visibles", no solamente encontrar cuales son visibles y cuales no